# Callbacks in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, asynchronous, callback

I have two classes. `ClassA`, with two methods, `MethodA` and `MethodB`. And `ClassB`, with `MethodC`.

I want to have `ClassA.MethodA` call `ClassB.MethodC` (which will be running asynchronously in the background), and when `ClassB.MethodC` finishes, it triggers a callback to call `ClassA.MethodB` (along with some parameters passed back).

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Possible to declare method_C like this: - (oneway void)mothod_C. And it will be called async
2. You can use dispatch_async and completion block. Not comfortable as for me.

   ```
   MethodA
   {
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
       ^{
           MethodC_withComplition:
           ^{
               weak_classA.MethodB
           }
       })
   }
   ```
3. May be used [ClassB performSelectorInBackground:@selector(MethodC) withObject:@[callingThread, callbackSelector]] 
   or equivalent
   [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(methodC:) toTarget:classB withObject:@[callingThread, callbackSelector]] and use callbackSelector on thread that invokes this task.
4. Use NSInvocationOperation with ClassB and selector MethodC with callback in arguments, and push to the operation queque. At the end of MethodC use [ClassA performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(callbackSelector:)]
5. If it possible, introduce you own operation for this background task(subclass of NSOperation) with simple callback.

As for me, is preferable to use NSOperation subclass - variant 4. Of course if it available in you case.

Comment: Ended up using dispatch_asynch

Answer (score 1):

If MethodC is strongly connected to methodB I would send parameter with completion block:

### ClassA

```
- (void)methodC {
    void(^blockName)(parameterTypes) = ^void(parameters) {
        // The code that should be done after methodB finish.
    };
    [self.instanceOfClassA:blockName];
}
```

### ClassB

```
- (void)methodB:(void(^)(parameterTypes))blockName {
   // Do what you need to here in method B.
   blockName(parameters);
}
```

Such problem you can also solve using delegates or `ReactiveCocoa`. The `RACSignal`'s are a really good way to manage the flow control between different classes.

Comment: Thanks to your hint, I ended up using delegates. I did not even know there is such thing (I am new to Objective C). Thanks.